# Query text of ng-Container with @ContentChild

Tags: angular

I want to use the text which is passed to the following component via `ng-content`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class ChildComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild('value') text: ElementRef;
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    // This does not work
    let value = this.text.nativeElement.nextSibling.textContent as string;
  }
}
```

The parent component includes it like this:

```html
<child-component>
  <ng-container #value>My Content</ng-container>
</child-component>
```

How can I get the string "My Content" from the ContentChild?

Comment: Is it not working? https://plnkr.co/edit/nkqXNNzBVkZ79PzG8u2u?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

`ng-container` is transformed into a comment node and the content that you place inside will be rendered as a sibling node, so the following:

```
<ng-container #value>My Content</ng-container>
```

is transformed into something like this:

```
nodes:
    [<!-- ng contentainer -->]
    ['My content']
```

So you can access the text as `nextSibling` using either `textContent` or `nodeValue` property:

```
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    // This does not work
    let value = this.vs.nativeElement.nextSibling.nodeValue as string;
  }
```

Comment: Oh, wow. This is amazing, and really, really, REALLY helps me. I've spent 20 hours on this already. So is there ANY way to get the children of a `ng-container` via directive? (Via `@viewChildren`, or `@contentChildren`, or, hell, even `Render2` or something similar? ) Aside from doing something horrible like `nativeElement.nextSibling`.

Comment: (I'm trying to add a directive to a mat-table's column, and get the `elementRef` inside it.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I ran into was that my content is not static:

```
<child-component *ngFor="let content of array">
  <ng-container #value>{{ content }}</ng-container>
</child-component>
```

So after I used the *AfterViewInit* lifecycle hook instead of *AfterContentInit*, it works well.
If the content was static, the code in my question would be correct, as noticed in yurzui's comment.